# Kotlin unresolved reference to local package

Tags: kotlin, import, package

File `./Main.kt`:

```
import numbers

fun main() {
    var value = numbers.sum(7, 4)
}
```

File `./numbers/Operations.kt`:

```
package numbers

fun sum(val1: Int, val2: Int): Int {
    return val1 + val2
}
```

Running the command `kotlinc Main.kt` outputs:

```
Main.kt:1:8: error: unresolved reference: numbers
import numbers

Main.kt:4:17: error: unresolved reference: numbers
var value = numbers.sum(2, 3)
```

If I try to add `import java` (I am new in Kotlin ans I saw someone imported this. I thought it is a part of a standard library) then output also contains:

```
Main.kt:1:8: error: packages cannot be imported
import java
```

What I did wrong?

**SOLUTION (Thanks to @gidds):**

Was need to pass each file to the complier, not like with Java compiler (`javac`)

```
kotlinc Main.kt numbers/Operations.kt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`numbers` is a package.  And, as the error says, `packages cannot be imported`.  Only classes, functions, or properties.

If you `import numbers.sum`, you should find you can call it with e.g. `sum(7, 4)`.

Or you could call its fully-qualified name directly, without the import: `numbers.sum(7, 4)`.

It's the same with `java`, which is also a package.  You can import `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap` (a class), but not `java`, `java.util`, nor `java.util.concurrent` (which are all packages).  (Java has the same restriction.)

Comment: `unresolved reference: numbers`, `import numbers.sum` [image](https://ibb.co/F7rpGqL)

Comment: @Don2Quixote Try including Operations.kt on the compiler command line.  (Kotlin doesn't require packages to match the folder structure, so it won't know where to find source code unless you tell it.)  Most people use an IDE which takes care of all that.

Comment: This worked! I tried to do like with `javac`, this resolve files automatically without passing them. And what for now? If I want to include `java.util.concurrent.concurrentHashMp` - I need to find it in my system and pass to the compiler absolute path?

Comment: @Don2Quixote `java.` classes are part of the Java installation, just as `kotlin.` classes are part of the Kotlin installation, so your system should already know about them.  The details depend on how you're running it, of course; IDEs and Gradle all have their own methods.  If you're running the `kotlin` or `java` executables, those should know where to find them.  (If you're running `java`, you'll need to add the Kotlin jar(s) — `kotlin-stdlib.jar` &c — to the classpath yourself.)